# Python - how to return values from function in other script

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import, method-call

I want to return a value in a script MAIN.py where the function is stated in another script? How do I do this?

In a function SUB.py I have defined:

```
def SUM_POWER(a,b):
    c = a+b
    d = a**b
    return [c,d]
```

Now I want to get in a script MAIN.py:
c and d for a=3 and b=4. I tried in MAIN.py:

```
import SUB
c,d = SUM_POWER(3,4)
```

What do I do wrong? Preferably I would want to name the variables in MAIN.py different than c,d. So for example out1, out2. out1 has to correspond to c and out2 corresponds to d by the order in which the values are returned.

Comment: use `from SUB import SUM_POWER`

Comment: either `from SUB import SUM_POWER` or use `import SUB` but call it with `SUB.SUM_POWER`. Also `SUM_POWER` should return a tuple not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in function call, as well as that you are returning a list while trying to store it in a tuple.

Try this SUB.py -

```
def SUM_POWER(a,b):
c = a+b
d = a**b
return c,d
```

MAIN.py -

```
import SUB
c,d = SUB.SUM_POWER(3,4)
```